# Any element $\alpha \in \pi_1(M)$ can be represented by a smooth closed path without self-intersections

Tags: manifolds, fundamental-groups

Like the title says, any element $\alpha \in \pi_1(M)$ can be represented by a smooth closed path without self-intersections, if the manifold $M$ is of dimension $3$ or higher, as "there is enough room to get rid of the self-intersections in any closed path by means of arbitrarily small deformations". This argument makes sense, but I don't know how I would properly write that down in mathematical terms.

Comment: Do you know Sard's theorem?

Comment: @JohnHughes No i don't. From what i gathered from 3 minutes of research, it is about the countability of these intersections?

Comment: If you know about transversality, this is easy. My suggestion is to read first few chapters of Guillemin and Pollack "Differential Topology".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch. I can add more details, but this would require some basic understanding of transversality on your part.

Let $M, N$ be smooth manifolds of dimensions $m, n$ respectively, so that $n> 2m$ and $M$ is compact. Then given any smooth map $f: M\to N$, we obtain the map of squares:
$$
f^2:=f\times f: M\times M\to N\times N.
$$
Now, one can make a small perturbation $g$ of $f$ to make $g^2$ transversal to the diagonal $\Delta\subset N\times N$. The dimension count yields $2m=dim(M\times M)< dim(\Delta)$. Hence, the perturbed map satisfies the property that $im(g^2)\cap \Delta=\emptyset$. Therefore, $g$ is 1-1. A similar argument involving $df$ ensures existence of a small perturbation which is also an immersion, hence, an embedding. Furthermore, for a sufficiently small perturbation, $g$ is homotopic to $f$. Now, apply this to $M=S^1$.

Comment: If $[f] \in \pi_1(M, m_0)$, is it clear that $g$ will be homotopic to $f$ as based maps?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Once $f(0)=g(0)=m_0$ (which is again easy to arrange), then $f$ will be homotopic to $g$ as based maps (put a Riemannian metric on $N$ and use the straight-line homotopy). I am not even using the assumption that $dim(M)=1$ here, only compactness of $M$. Actually, one does not even need a straight-line homotopy. manifestly homotopic. (Not preserving the base-point though).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: What makes the whole thing work is the existence of a map $F: M\times I^k\to N$ such that $F(\cdot, 0)=f$ and such that $F^2: M^2\times I^k\to N^2$ is a submersion to $N^2$. Then for generic $t\in I^k$, the map $F^2(\cdot, t)$ is transversal to $\Delta$. The maps $F(\cdot, t), f$ are then manifestly homotopic. (Not preserving the base-point though). The last thing to use is the isotopy extension property to take care of the basepoints.

Comment: "I can add more details" I would definitely like to see more details if you have the time. In particular, the issues regarding basepoints. Alternatively, if you know of a reference that proves the result in detail, I would be happy to see that too.